# navigation drawer and RecyclerView listeners clash

Tags: android

I use RecyclerView and navigation Drawer in my project. And I realize swipe to dismiss on my RecyclerView. But it work very not-sensitivity. I think it is becose swipe listener navigation drawer and RecyclerView clash.

my RecyclerView :

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };
```

When i toch item It does not react. But with the many attempts it work. Why?

my meny listener

```
private ResideMenu.OnMenuListener menuListener = new ResideMenu.OnMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void openMenu() {
            Observer.getInstance().send(MessageType.SCAN_STATUS, new ScanEvent(false));
        }

        @Override
        public void closeMenu() {
            Observer.getInstance().send(MessageType.SCAN_STATUS, new ScanEvent(true));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hmm, I used a different method and I put it in my `onCreate`. Instead of on Menu Listener, I used `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: I am sorry i use not drawer i use  https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu